# Connect custom UI elements with data

Tags: java, javafx

I am thinking about how to do this in  a good way.
I have created a program that shows some custom shapes in the GUI. Now when I hover the mouse over an element I want to show some information that is related to that element.
In this example lets imagine that each element is a person so I want to show some basic information about that person (Name, birthdate, sex ...) on mouse hover.

How do i connect the data i have about a person to the element data represents the person?

As far as i see there is to ways to do this.

1. I embed the data directly in the shape. (Not sure how to do this)
2. I use the ID of the shape to lookup the data.

Comment: You should post some code what you tried so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can associate custom data with any JavaFX node, using `setUserData(Object)` and `getUserData()`

Therefore in your case you would simply store the `Person` in the shape

```
shape.setUserData(person);
```

and within the mouse over event retrieve it to display the data:

```
(Person)shape.getUserData();
```

Comment: or shape.getProperties().put(...)

Comment: Given that you are creating custom UI elements anyway, this seems like a really poor solution. Relying on a non-typesafe map with no mechanism to guarantee the data exist, or are of the correct type, just seems incredibly fragile. If you're creating your own UI elements, why not just create a property to hold the data?

Comment: @James_D I think this is an unfair comment. In my eyes to be able to associate UI objects with custom data **is** a useful feature, especially if you **don't** derive an own class. And whether this leads to unstable code is simple a matter how one uses the feature. At least it showed one way to the OP how to establish such an association.

Comment: @wero It's an opinion, of course, but using this technique you are going to end up with lots of Java 1.4 style code (null checks, `instanceof` checks, downcasts, etc), or just have to blindly trust that other parts of your application are doing the right thing. The OP presumably *is* writing their own class here (though (s)he couldn't be bothered to include any code in the question) so far more robust solutions are probably just as easy to create.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different solution, which I think is far more robust than using the essentially untyped [`userData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setUserData-java.lang.Object-) or [`properties` map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getProperties--). Using either of those approaches will either clutter your code with checks for `null` and for things being the right type, or will force you to assume code all over your application uses the UI elements the correct way. The first of these will make it much harder to read (and therefore maintain) your code. The second means that your code is vulnerable to bugs that can be hard to track down (because they occur in code that may be far from the code where they materialize).

Either you are creating your UI elements by subclassing them, or you have a method (or some block of code) to create them. In the first case, you just give the subclass a reference to the data it needs:

```
public class PersonNode extends Region {

    private final Person person ;

    /**
    * @parameter person The person this node represents.
    * @throws NullPointerException if person is null.
    **/
    public PersonNode(Person person) {
        if (person == null) throw new NullPointerException("Person cannot be null");

        // do layout, add nodes to children list, etc...

        this.person = person ;

        Popup popup = createPopup();
        this.setOnMouseEntered(e -> popup.show(this, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY()));
        this.setOnMouseExited(e -> popup.hide());

    }

    private Popup createPopup() {
        Label nameLabel = new Label();
        nameLabel.textProperty().bind(person.nameProperty());
        Label birthdayLabel = new Label();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM yyyy");
        birthdayLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
            () -> formatter.format(person.getBirthday()),
            person.birthdayProperty()
        ));
        // etc...
        VBox root = new VBox(10, nameLabel, birthdayLabel);
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        popup.getContent().add(root);
        return popup ;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person ;
    }
}
```

Now your application code is simple:

```
List<Person> personList = ... ;
Pane somePane = ... ;

somePane.getChildren().addAll(
    personList.stream().map(PersonNode::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

and it's also straightforward to add other UI functionality:

```
for (Person person : personList) {
    PersonNode node = new PersonNode(person);
    node.setOnMouseClicked(e -> showPersonEditor(node.getPerson()));
    somePane.getChildren().add(node);
}
```

Even if you don't want a custom UI class, you can still get much of the same effect by factoring the node creation into a method:

```
public Node createNodeForPerson(Person person) {

    Pane personNode = new Pane(); // probably actually use a real layout pane here...
    // configure personNode with controls or graphics, etc

    Label nameLabel = new Label();
    nameLabel.textProperty().bind(person.nameProperty());
    Label birthdayLabel = new Label();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM yyyy");
    birthdayLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
        () -> formatter.format(person.getBirthday()),
        person.birthdayProperty()
    ));
    // etc...
    VBox root = new VBox(10, nameLabel, birthdayLabel);
    Popup popup = new Popup();
    popup.getContent().add(root);

    personNode.setOnMouseEntered(e -> popup.show(personNode, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY()));
    personNode.setOnMouseExited(e -> popup.hide());
    return personNode ;
}
```

(What is happening here is that the popup contains a reference to the `Person` via the bindings that are defined. The `personNode` holds a reference to the popup via the mouse listeners, so it effectively keeps a reference to the `Person` data.)

Now of course you do things like

```
for (Person person : personList) {
    somePane.getChildren().add(createNodeForPerson(person));
}
```